# uninstalling applications using SCCM SDK

Tags: sccm

I have been trying to uninstall applications on devices or users using SCCM. I have been successful in creating an application assignment that would install applications, but I haven't been able to get it to uninstall. The code I have been using is:

```
IResultObject assignment = this.manager.CreateInstance("SMS_ApplicationAssignment");
IResultObject application =
        this.manager.GetInstance("SMS_Application.CI_ID=16777339");

assignment["ApplicationName"].StringValue = application["LocalizedDisplayName"].StringValue;
assignment["AssignedCI_UniqueID"].StringValue = application["CI_UniqueID"].StringValue;
assignment["AssignedCIs"].IntegerArrayValue = new[] { application["CI_ID"].IntegerValue};
assignment["AssignmentName"].StringValue = "Deepak's deployment";
assignment["CollectionName"].StringValue = "Deepak's Collection of Devices";
assignment["DisableMomAlerts"].BooleanValue = true;
assignment["NotifyUser"].BooleanValue = false;
assignment["OfferFlags"].IntegerValue = 0;
assignment["DesiredConfigType"].IntegerValue = 1;           
assignment["OverrideServiceWindows"].BooleanValue = false;
assignment["RebootOutsideOfServiceWindows"].BooleanValue = false;
assignment["SuppressReboot"].IntegerValue = 0;
assignment["TargetCollectionID"].StringValue = "UKN0000F";
assignment["EnforcementDeadline"].DateTimeValue = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
assignment["StartTime"].DateTimeValue = DateTime.Now;
assignment["UseGMTTimes"].BooleanValue = false;
assignment["UserUIExperience"].BooleanValue = false;
assignment["WoLEnabled"].BooleanValue = false;
assignment["RequireApproval"].BooleanValue = true;
assignment["OfferTypeId"].IntegerValue = 2;
assignment.Put();
```

This code will put up the application as an install deployment in SCCM. How do I get it as an uninstall deployment?
There is an `AppAction` enumeration, which I suspect is used by the client and not on the server.

```
typedef enum AppAction
{
    appDiscovery = 0, 
    appInstall = 1, 
    appUninstall = 2
} AppAction;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The setting that needs to be changed is **DesiredConfigType**.

For your code add the following before **put()**:

```
assignment["DesiredConfigType"].IntegerValue = 2;
```

A value of 1 represents install (required) and 2 will uninstall (not allowed).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh949014.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is first use [uninstall.exe](http://www.tarma.com/support/uninstall.htm) to determine the guid of the program, and then create a program for the package I wish to uninstall, and just call uninstall.exe /whatever as the command. This works for most apps that show up in Add/Remove, and if it doesn't show up there then it'll have to be a hack (or script) anyway to uninstall. I believe the reason you're falling short is because if there is no command to uninstall the *deployment* in sccm, then it has nothing to run.

After you create an uninstall program, you could just call that deployment from your code, and voila.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the target program that you are trying to use was installed via an MSI (Microsoft Installer) then you can loop through the registry to find your product (Registry Location: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall") And just look at each DisplayName value.

In our environment, I accomplish this task by using Powershell, and we setup a program that specifically uninstalls whatever we are after.

Hope this helps...
Raged.